# Java-Spring, strange NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dwr

I'll explain the situation.
I have an application web, java + spring + hibernate. Actually, i want to integrate DWR with Spring, so I did all the configuration and I think what I did works fine since I get this windows:

[image]

Now, we can focus on the `findUsername(String username)` methodo inside the dwr code:

```
@Autowired 
UserBo userBo;

public boolean findUsername(String username) {

    System.out.println("I'm in the DWR");

    try {

        User user = userBo.findByUsername(username);

        if(user != null) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the code of `userBo.findByUsername(String username)` methodo:

```
public User findByUsername(String username) {
    System.out.println("I'm in the BO");
    return userDao.findByUsername(username);
}
```

And the DAO Code:

```
@Transactional
public User findByUsername(String username) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    System.out.println("I'm in the DAO");

    String hql = "FROM User Tab WHERE Tab.username= :username";

    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

    query.setParameter("username", username);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> userFound = (List<User>) query.list();
    if (userFound.size() > 0) {

        session.close();
        return userFound.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But when the code reach `userBo.findByUsername(username);` method call i get the NullPointerException.

I'm pretty sure the bo + day working good because I've used it in some other part of the application.

I don't understand the problem.
Can someone help me?

EDIT: The StackTrace

```
lcc.dwr.CCServiceDWR.findUsername(CCServiceDWR.java:26)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule$1.doFilter(CreatorModule.java:229)
org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule.executeMethod(CreatorModule.java:241)
org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:379)
org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:332)
org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:104)
org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120)
org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrController.handleRequestInternal(DwrController.java:234)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @Xstian since i'm in a DWR the console doesn't show me the stacktrace :S

Comment: @madhairsilence nope.. i've tried lot of cases :S

Comment: Use debug mode and check objects value

Comment: added the stacktrace

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but you never mentioned if the username that is passed in the query is actually a value in the database, could that be it?

Comment: @JRSofty Thanks for the answer, but i get the error before the code  go into the dao code, then before the query.

Comment: What is line 26 of `CCServiceDWR.java` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta its the call of the method.
I've seen the userBo is Null at this time. But dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I misses this line in the dwr-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="lcc.*" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If spring context is fully initialized spring guarantees that all @autowired fields are not-null beans.

However if you call some bean's method before spring context is fully initialized, the @autowired field can be null.

Check if you call `findUsername(String username)` before context is ready and if yes - this may be the reason...

If you want to do some call and be sure that context is ready try such pattern:

```
@Component
public class SpringContextMonitor implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

  @Autowired
  private SomeDao dao;

  ...

  @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            onStart((ContextRefreshedEvent) event);
        }
    }

  private void onStart(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

    // do your initialization here
    dao.getSomething();
    dao2.getSomething();
    ...

  }

  ...
}
```

In that code, method onStart is call just after context become ready.

Comment: So... what ive to do? (i've added the stacktrace)

Comment: Your stacktrace shows that call to `findUsername` is when your spring context is ready - so this is not the problem I have written. Another idea is that your bean that have userBo autowired is not on spring's scan path, so spring does not inject userBo. You should turn on spring logs (level debug) and see if spring is trying to inject userBo component.

Comment: At the time of findUsername call the userBo is Null. That's is why i get the NullPointerException.
But in some other part of the application i've already user the @autowired for UserBo with no problems

Comment: Thanks to You i've found the problem